# Autohotkey: How to get a command to act as a key?

Tags: autohotkey

Due to two keys being broken I want to be able to make the 'I' and 'O' to be mapped to a command, so for example mapping 'O' to ALT+P or something.

Thanks (noob at autohotkey)

Answer (score 0):

Remapping in AutoHotKey or AutoIt follows the syntax

```
a::b
```

where `a` is the key or key combination to press (action) and `b` is the key that is send to your application (reaction)

There are 4 modifier keys which can be combined with a base key. You cannot combine two base keys at once in an easy way (However, it is possible). If you want to combine a key with a modifier, you simple put its symbol in front of it

- `#` stands for <kbd>WIN</kbd>
- `!` stands for <kbd>ALT</kbd>
- `^` stands for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
- `+` stands for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>
- `*` stands for any of the four modifiers

To remap <kbd>ALP</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to <kbd>O</kbd> you would use

```
!p::o
```

### Tips

- If you don't want to block the native key function of <kbd>ALP</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> you put a `~` sign in front like `~!p::o`
- Function keys and special keys like <kbd>F1</kbd> or arrow keys are accessed with curly brackets: `{F1}`
- If you want to disable a certain a key, then you map it to `return` like `a::return`
- Beside the normal mapping you can also use [`Send`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) like `a::Send {LAlt}`

### Further Reading

- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm
- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm
- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm